# Using Access 2003 VBA, I want to be able to have a report come up on the screen, not print out. But it doesn't work

Tags: ms-access, vba

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.
I am using a case statement to determine which report to print. I have determined that the correct case statement is chosen. Here is the case statement:

```
Public Function RunAll(Vvar As Integer)

    Select Case Vvar

        Case 1
            'Case Me.frmeReports.Value = 1
            DoCmd.OpenReport "rptClientDev", acViewPreview

        Case 2
            'Case Me.frmeReports.Value = 2
            DoCmd.OpenReport "rptNetworking", , , , acViewPreview

        Case 3
            'Case Me.frmeReports.Value = 3
            DoCmd.OpenReport "rptSpeaking", , , , acViewPreview

        Case 4
            'Case Me.frmeReports.Value = 4
            DoCmd.OpenReport "rptArticle", , , , acViewPreview

    End Select

End Function
```

This function is called from the following subroutine:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

    If Me.ChkRunOne.Value = -1 Then
        strAttName = Me.cmbAttyName.Value
        vReportChoice = Me.frmeReports.Value
        RunOnce (vReportChoice)
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm ("frmMainMenu")

    Else
        vReportChoice = Me.frmeReports.Value
        RunAll (vReportChoice)
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm ("frmMainMenu")

    End If

End Sub
```

The reports print correctly, with the right values. The problem is that I don't want them to print, I want them to come up on the screen. You can see with the Case 1 statement that I tried using fewer commas between arguments, but the result is the same. The report prints and then the database closes. I'm totally confused here.

-Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Syntax from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238032(v=office.12).aspx, 2003 is the same.

```
expression.OpenReport ReportName, View, FilterName, WhereCondition, WindowMode, OpenArgs
```

So all these

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptNetworking", , , , acViewPreview
```

are wrong, there are too many commas.

The first one is right.

Answer (score 0):

This is about your secondary note - the one about unexpected closure of the database:

I think this might be caused by careless use of `DoCmd.Close`: when you call this method without any arguments it closes the *currently active* window which is not necessarily the window you really wanted to close. In this particular case you're opening a whole bunch of report windows just before calling `DoCmd.Close` - which window do you think becomes active by the time of call? ;-)

It's a good practice to always use specific window (e.g. form) reference when calling `DoCmd.Close` (see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226008%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more details).